# Сколько и какие JIT-компиляторы есть в .NET 6?

Tags: .net, jit

В книге Visual C# 2010 написано, что существуют несколько JIT-компиляторов, и каждый рассчитан на конкретную архитектуру, поэтому стало интересно, что есть из JIT-компиляторов в наборе .NET 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше действительно существовали разные JIT под разные архитектуры, с разными принципами работы: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler-for-net/. До .NET Framework 4.6 (2013 г.) был x86 JIT, оптимизированный под быструю компиляцию, и x64 JIT - "серверный", более тяжелый, но применяющий больше оптимизаций при генерации кода. В тех версиях часто код работал по-разному при разных архитектурах, не только в плане скорости, но и в плане времени жизни переменных.

Сейчас этого нет, есть один [RyuJIT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/jit/ryujit-overview.md), который основан на старом x86 JIT, но поддерживает разные архитектуры: x86, x64, ARM. Это не считая Mono JIT, который теперь находится в том же репозитории, что и .NET, но все равно идет несколько отдельно (он задействован только под Xamarin.Android).